# Using a variable inside xsl:text in roundrect tag in xslt

Tags: html, xml, email, xslt, html-email

I am new to xslt coding and need your help. I am designing an email template using xslt and I have created a button using styling. This button is displayed only when the receiver is Microsoft outlook(mso). Following is the code. Please pay attention to the href attribute inside v:roundrect tag.

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!--[if gte mso 9]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{$URL}" style="height:37px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:190px;" arcsize="15%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#557d9a">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration: none;">
           Verify Email Address 
        </center>
    </v:roundrect> <![endif]-->]]> </xsl:text>
```

I have used a variable called 'URL', which is the value of the element:

```
<xsl:variable name="URL">
      <xsl:value-of select="ASBMessage/LinkURL"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

However, the output which comes is not as expected. The variable url value doesnt come and {$URL}' comes as it is behind the button. Any idea how to use the variable value in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write it like this...

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!--[if gte mso 9]>]]></xsl:text>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{$URL}" style="height:37px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:190px;" arcsize="15%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#557d9a">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration: none;">
       <xsl:text>Verify Email Address</xsl:text> 
    </center>
</v:roundrect> 
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<![endif]-->]]></xsl:text>
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables inside `<xsl:text>`, you have to terminate the `</xsl:text>`, then place the `<xsl:value-of select="$URL"/>` and then continue the text.

Comment: you are right @Stefan. I changed the code as per your suggestion. Works fine now. Thank you :)